# How to add article to the basic page

Tags: 7

I am completely new to **Drupal 7**. I have made slider from the **views slideshow** .As I am making my site multilingual, I have set my slider in basic page and made it the front page.

But my question is that, right now it is having only the static data below the slider.But Is there any way to post recent articles in place of that static data ?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: How did you do your Views Slideshow *in* a basic page? Anyway, you can create a second View (using a block) with recent articles and have it displayed in main content region restricted to `<front>` page.

Comment: Ok thanks.I will give it a try and get back to you soon.